# GPU Programming on non openCL compliant Graphic Chip for Mac OSX

Tags: cocoa, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I have been playing around, trying to implement an openCL GPU computing layer in my Mac OSX Cocoa app, just to realize that my 13" Macbook Pro Late 2011 and it's Intel HD3000 graphic chip doesn't comply with openCL !

What are my alternatives to get my GPU to do any computation ?

Comment: Buy a new computer? If your MBP has Thunderbolt you could try to get an external Thunderbolt GPU working, but that's a huge hack and not terribly cheap to set up.

Comment: @NicholasRiley By that I meant there are no other languages i could use, drivers I could update, etc., something I could have missed that somehow enabled me to use my GPU to achieve anything ?

Comment: Nope, you're just running into hardware limitations.  OpenCL isn't supported on any Intel graphics before the Ivy Bridge/HD4000 generation, with any operating system or SDK.

Comment: @NicholasRiley So how does any dev can harvest GPU power prior to 2011 Macbook ? They just cant ?

Comment: You can write OpenGL shaders, and do some GPGPU work with those. You're a lot more limited than what you can do with OpenCL, but it might be good enough for what you want. Even there, the Intel integrated graphics were very weak.

Comment: @BradLarson That's the kind of stuff I was looking for, would you have some resources (example projects, blog articles ...) to direct me to so as to make an answer out of it ?

Comment: I concur with the information here so far (OpenCL not possible on HD3000, but you could use GLSL on it). Here are two PDFs on the topic: http://www.computer-graphics.se/gpu-computing/2a.pdf‎ and http://glsl-intro-shaders.googlecode.com/files/glsl-intro-survey.pdf‎ and a web page: http://gpgpu.org/developer/legacy-gpgpu-graphics-apis

Comment: @Dithermaster Thanks, I guess openGL is the key. No one wants to make an answer and get the rep ^^ ?